# Auto increment column for specific Id in some table related to anther table C# mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a table named Payment which has a column named IndexOrder and  all I need when I add a new payment, the AddEdit function will check first if there is any value in IndexOrder Column for this specific Id then increment Indexorder with 1 and so on for every new PaymentId. my AddEdit function code is like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEdit(PaymentModel model  )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        Payment obj = context.Payment
                .Where(p => p.Id == model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = new Payment();
            if (model.File != null)
            {
                Guid nme = Guid.NewGuid();
                string filename = nme + Path.GetExtension(model.File.FileName);
                string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/FilesUpload/") + filename);
                model.File.SaveAs(filepath);
                obj.Path = filename;
            }
            Mapper.FillObjectFromModel(obj, model);
            obj.CreatedBy = userId;
            obj.ModifiedBy = userId;
            obj.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            obj.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
            context.Payment.Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Simply use auto increment in your database if you are using a database

Answer (score 0):

So did i get that right? For every new payment that relates to a specific id (assuming a product or something) you want aincremented IndexOrder?

I would not use an IndexOrder column for that but instead just order by timestamp. Assuming you need that for kind of transactionhistory just read them payments like

```
context.Payments.Where(x => x.ProductId == myProductId).OrderBy(x => x.timestamp);
```

But to answer your question this should be quite simple, e.g:

```
var nextIndex = context.Payments.Where(x => x.ProductId == myProductId).Count +1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for more details, the specific Id is a contract with some value and the company get the money by one or more invoice and for every invoice the user enters the system should give an auto number for this Payment because he will need to print out Payment Report with this auto number without interface from the user and it should be sequence